# Renaming openconnection() or cutting it up?

Tags: java, class, url

Is it possible to rename the openconnection()?

Orginal:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**openConnection**();
```

After:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**connect**();
```

I'm just wondering if it is possible and how I would go about doing it. Is there an alternative? I was thinking of making a class in order to do this, but I wasn't 100% sure if that would be possible.

<------------------ Or ---------------->

Orginal:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**openConnection**();
```

After:

```
string st1 = "open";
string st2 = "Connection";
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**st1 + st2**();
```

I get an error when I make it a string, but I'm not really sure how to make it combine the two to define that. If that makes since, I'm kinda rusty at coding with Java.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why not? I was just wondering out of curiosity and would like to see if it would be possible to do. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Jessica - It is not possible, without doing insanely stupid things.

Comment: This change has no practical value. What would you gain from it apart from confusing people who look at your code and are familiar with the standard API?

Comment: It has value to me. I'm not worried about other people looking at my code, I'm more or less just wanting to know if I can do it and how.

Comment: @Jessica Roth - so why don't you just explain what that "value" is ... because most of us think that this about as useful as standing on one leg and singing "God Save the Queen".

Comment: @Jessica: based on the various forms of your question, it really sounds like you might just want to use [a different JVM language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages).

Answer (score 9):

**Take this answer with a large bag of salt.** This *will* work but you generally don't want to muck around with reflection unless you're very comfortable with Java.

---

You can accomplish #2 with reflection, ignoring all sorts of nasty exceptions that you'll have to deal with:

```
String st1 = "open";
String st2 = "Connection";
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
Object obj = url.getClass().getMethod(st1 + st2).invoke(url);
URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) obj;
```

See:

- [`Object#getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)
- [`Class#getMethod(String, Class...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)
- [`Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

The potential exceptions you'll have to deal with somehow, from **one** line of code:

- [`NoSuchMethodException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html)
- [`SecurityException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html)
- [`IllegalAccessException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html)
- [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)
- [`InvocationTargetException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html)

---

I'm not really sure why you want to do this, though. There is almost certainly a better way to accomplish the same end result. **What is the bigger problem you're trying to solve?**

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can't do that directly. You can't derive from `URL` since it's final, so you'd have to write a proxy class, and that would be a waste of time and could introduce bugs.

For the second one, you could sort of do that using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/). It's not trivial to do,  that's an advanced topic. So I'd avoid that until you are **very** familiar with the Java language in general.

If you explained what you were trying to achieve, maybe you'd get better suggestions.