# Dynamic method invocation?

Tags: java, class, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming openconnection() or cutting it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453364/renaming-openconnection-or-cutting-it-up)

Orginal:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**openConnection**();
```

After:

```
string st1 = "open";
string st2 = "Connection";
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");
URLConnection connection = url.**st1 + st2**();
```

I get an error when I make it a String, but I'm not really sure how to make it combine the two to define that. Does that makes sense? I'm kinda rusty at coding with Java.

Comment: [You already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453364/renaming-openconnection-or-cutting-it-up). Please don't post the same question multiple times.  Editing the original one will "bump" it back in the question queue so that people will see it.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but Java does not really allow this without using reflection. Could you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to is possible. You are looking for `java.lang.reflect`.

```
String st1 = "open";
String st2 = "Connection";
URL url = new URL("http://google.co.in");

Class<URL> clazz = url.getClass();
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(st1 + st2);
URLConnection obj = (URLConnection) m.invoke(url);
```

Wrap this in a try-catch.